# Sudo is broken on linux mint 17.3

Tags: linux, linux-mint

When I execute

```
sudo apt-get install composer
```

Following error occurred:

```
sudo: error in /etc/sudo.conf, line 0 while loading plugin `sudoers_policy'
sudo: /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so must be only be writable by owner
sudo: fatal error, unable to load plugins
```

and don't know the root password. Please suggest me a solution

Comment: Boot from a live medium and fix the file permissions

Comment: check permission of this file /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so

Comment: -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 322064 this is the permission, but I'm not a root user

Comment: try to do sudo -i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your system is broken. Unless you changed the permission specifically on that file, there's a good chance other files are also affected by the same issue.

If it's just this file for some reason, you can boot from a live CD, mount your root filesystem, and run `chmod 0600 /path/to/usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so`.

Otherwise, either you or something you used ran `chmod 0777` on your `/usr` or other directory when it should never happen. Realistically, your best option in this case if to backup your data, reinstall the system and restore. You could attempt recovery, but since you posted this question, it's probably too advanced.